# Cucumber Java: How do I add (or subtract, multiply) previously stored variables dynamically?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Below, I have stored four numbers into variables and in the final step I want to ensure that total equals the sum of count1 through count3. How do I write it so that no matter the number of "count" variables I enter, I can use one single step definition?

```
Given User logs into "AppA" application of Application
When user gets count from "TotalLines" and stores into "$TotalRecords"
And user gets count from "Car1" and stores into "$Count1"
And user gets count from "Car2" and stores into "$Count2"
And user gets count from "Car3" and stores into "$Count3"
Then user validates that "$TotalRecords" is equal to the sum of "$Count1", "$Count2", and "$Count3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an arraylist of floats and name it as TotalRecords.

Now whenever you add a value of car in a count variable; instead of adding it into count variable; you can simply store it directly in the ArrayList.

Now at last you can finally find the sum of all values stored in that TotalRecords arraylist by using  a function as:

```
ArrayList<float> TotalRecords = new ArrayList<float>();
TotalRecords.add(carValue1);
TotalRecords.add(carValue2);
TotalRecords.add(carValue3);
TotalRecords.add(carValue4);
.
.
.
//now to add all the elements ; do this
public float Total(){
float sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < TotalRecords.size(); i++){
   sum+= TotalRecords.get(i);

 }
return sum;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the count values in a `List` or if required to keep the 'Car' part store in a `Map`.

Modify the scenario for the count lines to

```
And user gets count from "Car1"
And user gets count from "Car2"
And user gets count from "Car3"
```

Add the following in step definition class

```
   List<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<>();

    @When("^user gets count from \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void userGetsCountFromAndStores(String arg) {
        //Get count from the argument passed
        counts.add(countvalue);
    }
```

In the final step you can add the counts and compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DataTable for this:

```
When user gets the following variables:
  | count  | variable  |
  | "Car1" | "$Count1" |
  | "Car2" | "$Count2" |
  | "Car3" | "$Count3" |
```

In your step definition, you can use a DataTable as an argument, or you can use a List or Map with your type.